# What player actions or feats are available to disrupt enemy Cast a Spell actions?

Tags: opportunity-attack, spellcasting, pathfinder-2e

Obviously, the **Attack of Opportunity** has changed from 1e, now taking a Reaction instead and dependent on specific feat triggers.

There are a number of Triggers that reference manipulation actions, move actions and ranged attacks, but are there any that have Triggers regarding Cast a Spell and are capable of disrupting the action?

Answer (score 4):

- Rangers can select the level 4 feat [Disrupt Prey](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=501) reaction (per the 10/30/19 [errata](https://www.tabletopgamingnews.com/Paizo-Posts-Pathfinder-2nd-Edition-Errata)).
- [Wizards](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=633) and [Sorcerers](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=602) each have level 1 feat Counterspell Reactions.
- Rogues have a level 12 Feat to [Reactive Interference](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=585) that can Disrupt Reactions (including Reactive spellcasting)
- The [Stupefied](https://2e.aonprd.com/Conditions.aspx?ID=37) condition (page 622) Disrupts spells on a failed flat check.

Clarification on Attack of Opportunity:

[Attack of Opportunity](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=8) only Disrupts abilities that have [manipulate] on a critical.

> If your attack is a critical hit and the trigger was a manipulate action, you disrupt that action.

The level 10 Fighter feat [Disruptive Stance](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=401) allows you to interrupt Manipulate and Concentration and on a hit.

Comment: Also, you can Ready an action to trigger when someone cast a spell.

Comment: You can do so but attacks do not interrupt Manipulation/Concentration or Spells unlesss they say so (and those tend to be on a critical success)

Comment: Disrupt Prey is a reaction in the errata,

Answer (score 1):

Cast a Spell has traits that depend on the spell cast. Specifically, if the spell has any of Material, Somatic or Focus, then it has manipulate (CRB page 302).

If the spell is purely verbal, it may not.

**Anyone can** - with a free hand or a grapple weapon* - grapple a target no more than one size larger than them. On a success, the target has to make a flat DC 5 check to succeed at any manipulate action - including most spells. On a critical success, the target is restrained and cannot make actions with the manipulate trait - except specific actions to try and escape.

You could also ready the grapple attempt - with the trigger of them casting a spell, you might do this in order to waste some of the target's actions should you succeed - if you grapple on your turn, they might choose not to cast, and instead try to break free, or choose a spell without the manipulate trait. Where as if you readied the action, it has the same chance of interfering with their spell casting, but the don't know not to potentially waste actions casting before trying to break free.

However, note that readying an action instead of taking it on your turn does not allow you to avoid multiple attack penalties - which means that if readying your action to grapple you may want to find something to do with your third action other than attack.

**If you are trained in Athletics**, you could instead ready an action to Disarm the target - attempting to remove a necessary object for the spell casting from their hands, which on a critical success would prevent a spell that requires material or focus components.

**If you have Attack of Opportunity** One of Attack of Opportunity's triggers are actions with the Manipulate trait, and it disrupts the triggering manipulate actions on a critical hit.

**See Ifusaso's post for other similar acquirable abilities.**

*I believe the only grapple weapons in the CRB are from shape shifting - but others could be printed.

Answer (score -1):

**No.**  There is no action that triggers strictly on Cast any Spell and can also disrupt the action.  Actions that disrupt trigger on traits like manipulate and concentration.  Counterspell only works against some spells and counteracts instead of disrupting.  Ready doesn't disrupt, and the best you can do with your readied action is to Disarm a component or Grapple the caster.